# Looking for virus under Linux

Tags: linux, spyware

if I am looking for a virus/spyware under linux, where should I have to look for to find it ?

I suspect to be the target of very skilled hackers.
5 or 6 years ago I found a spyware on my linux box, it was lkm masked as ppp_deflate module with md5 hash hijacked. I mean with the same md5 hash of the original ppp_deflate. 
So my question is not "please advice me some kind of antirootkit tool" neither "Please give me some kind of malware for linux". I tryied different kinds of antirootkit tools but all had not worked.
And my question is:
I suspect I have a spyware on my linux box, where should I look for find this spyware ?
kernel ? lkm ? libc ? binary ? initrd ? gnome limited process ?
Then it's a kind of forensic question..
thanks

Comment: Are you looking for malware which targets Linux systems or are you looking for tools which run on linux for managing malware?

Answer (score 2):

Viruses and spyware are rare on Linux.  You can try Clam Antivirus, but generally speaking it is not worth the time.  Generally speaking, it is better to spend your time [hardening your Linux desktop](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4136/971) and [hardening your Linux servers](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/993/971), rather than worrying about anti-virus scanners.  Anti-virus scanners are primarily a Windows thing.

Why do you ask?

Comment: @Gilles,  could be possible reopen this question ?

Comment: @user45, you might be better off posting a totally new question, rather than revising the current one to add a lot of new  information.  Make sure to read the FAQ and provide all necessary background information: e.g., what Linux distribution and kernel you are using, and how you know (or why you suspect) you are infected with a virus/spyware.